# Somar variavel dentro do FOR

Tags: php, mysql

Bom pessoal, eu preciso gerar um relatório onde busca as pessoas que deram presença por dia, a pessoa pode ter mais de uma presença no mesmo dia, mas eu preciso puxar somente uma vez, então usei o "GROUP BY" para agrupar pelo id do usuário,e depois uso o mysqli_num_rows para contar quantos registros eu tenho nessa pesquisa, o problema é que tenho que apresentar a quantidade total de registro porém não estou conseguindo. Meu código está assim:

```
for($n=1;$n<= 26;$n++){
        $quant_enc = "SELECT * from presenca WHERE data_presenca = '$ano-$mes-$n' GROUP BY id_cad";
        $ex_enc = mysqli_query($conn,$quant_enc);
        $number_people = mysqli_num_rows($ex_enc);

        $html .= '<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">';
        $html .= '<thead>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>Nome</th>';
        $html .= '<td>Data Presença</th>';
        $html .= '<td>Horario</th>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '</thead>';


        while($rowsss = $ex_enc->fetch_array()){
            $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$rowsss['nomecad'].'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.date("d/m/Y", strtotime($rowsss['data_presenca'])) .'</td>';
            $html .= '<td>'.$rowsss['hora'].'</td>';
            $html .= '</tr>';


        }


      }
```

Como faço para pegar o resultado que tenho no $number_people e somar para todos os dias pesquisados ? Queria algo assim : Dia 01 = 300 pessoas , dia 02 = 200 [..] = Numero total de pessoas = 500 , ou existe maneiras mais fácil de conseguir o resultado que espero ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só criar uma variável antes e ir somando a cada iteração:

```
$total = 0;

for($n=1;$n<= 26;$n++){
    $quant_enc = "SELECT * from presenca WHERE data_presenca = '$ano-$mes-$n' GROUP BY id_cad";
    $ex_enc = mysqli_query($conn,$quant_enc);
    $number_people = mysqli_num_rows($ex_enc);

    $total += $number_people;

    // [...]
}

$html .= '<p>Total: $total</p>';
```